# Magento 2 : Update product price in plugin

Tags: magento2, product, php

I want to update product price each time customer open a page, so the price will be real time. I tried to use a plugin to change it when getPrice is called, but it always fails, here is my plugin code :

Plugin :

```
namespace Test\Show\Plugin;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
class Product
{
    protected $productRepository;

    public function __construct(
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,        
        array $data = []
    )
    {    
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getLoadProducts($id)
    {
        return $product = $this->productRepository->getById($id, true);
    }

    public function afterGetPrice(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject, $result)
    {
        $product = $this->getLoadProducts($subject->getId());
        $product->setPrice(1000);
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Is there any way to change product price from the plugin?

Comment: Did you setup the plugin definition in your extension's di.xml file?

Comment: I don't understand your __construct() method. You're not extending a class, but your constructor is calling its parent constructor method (and it's passing a $context object that doesn't exist). You need to remove that line (parent::__construct($context, $data);).

Comment: Yes i am, i want to change the products price not only for frontend, but backend too.